# ListActivity or PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, listactivity, preferenceactivity

My app, on startup, will require a "Wizard" of sorts, needing some bits of info from the user.

ID# (EditText)

What Section? (From List pulled from Server)

What Table (in Said Section)? (From List Pulled From Server)

Which Seat (At Said Table)? (From List not pulled, but validated against server)

I started making this a series of AlertDialogs and I found myself awash in a nest of twisty callbacks. That had to be the wrong approach, I figured.

So ListActvity or a PreferenceActivity?

It seems I would get almost everything I need from making this as a PreferenceActivity. I might get stuff I don't need (like persistence of the choices until the next run), but I can fix that.

The only catch is:

The List of Valid Section comes from a ServerApp, as does the List of Tables, once the Section is chose. I also don't want the user to be let off this screen until he's filled in all of the blanks.

At the risk of a mod flagging this question as "too vague" (I don't think it is -- I suspect many people have this question. I just don't see it asked), is this the wrong tool for the job, and if so, what would be?

Comment: whats wrong with a `android.preference.DialogPreference`?

Comment: Quite possibly nothing except my not having found this before. Will this be modal? Can the items in it launch selection lists to choose from on their own?

The thing I liked about the Preference Activity was that the user would recognize the questions he was going to be asked and why as the other options became enabled.

Comment: yes, its modal, and if you dont want everything to be in one place (inside `ScrollView` for example) you can use a simple `android.widget.ViewAnimator` and add "wizard pages" to it